# How to read in a huge csv zipped file in python?

Tags: python, zip

I have a few really big .zip files. Each contains 1 huge .csv.

When I try to read it in, I either get a memory error or everything freezes/crashes.

I've tried this:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('Eve.zip', 'r')
df1 = zf.read('Eve.csv')
```

but this gives a MemoryError.

I've done some research and tried this:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('Events_WE20200308.zip', 'r') as z:
    with z.open('Events_WE20200308.csv') as f:       
        for line in f:
            df=pd.DataFrame(f)
            print(line)
```

but I can't get it into a dataframe.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Your *for* loop makes no sense. You are repeatedly trying to construct a Dataframe from **f**. Also, how much RAM to you have available and how big is the unzipped csv file on disk?